# Why do many masechtot conclude with a portion of Aggadata?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, agada-stories-legends

From what I've seen, many *Masechtot* in Shas seem to conclude with an *aggadata* portion that can be found towards the end of that particular *Masechta*.

Is there a documented or stated reason as to why this is?

Comment: Have you checked to see if this is a pattern at the end of a perek or even of a discussion of a mishna? The conversation strays, having dealt with the original topic, until a new mishna (perek) refocuses it. The end of the masechta just has no refocus point.

Comment: Probably to recite Kaddish on Aggada

Comment: This would be stronger if you could document examples of this phenomenon (ideally sufficiently many examples to suggest it's more common than statistics would expect on average)

Comment: The last tosfos in Kesubos (112b) may be relevant here - he says that the gemara likes to end with a davar tov. I think in some places, potentially the end of nazir might follow similar reasoning